NanoXLSX: sheet's color
I am using NanXlSX to print documents in Excel, I need to add several sheets with a different color, I have been dealing with the style function but without any success. Please, can anybody tell me if in fact it is possible? Thanks

"I need to add several sheets with a different color" do you mean the worksheet tab colour? I don't know whether it's possible or not with Nano XLSX but here's an answered question that uses OpenXML

Yes, exactly, the worksheet tab colour. Many thanks, it seems it works with OpenXML, but I need NanoXLSX. Thanks!
